# UIButton embeded in UIVIew no responsible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uibutton

I have a problem

i created 6 `UIButtons` put them in a `UIView1`

then put the `UIView1` into another `UIView2`

then return `UIView2` as `UITableView.tableHeaderView`

now the problem is when i touch the buttons

no responsiblity

here is some information
1. `UIButtons` `UIView1` `UIView2` fremes are these

```
    2017-06-04 16:26:40.014 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :8.000000 8.000000 70.500000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.014 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :86.500000 8.000000 71.000000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.014 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :165.500000 8.000000 70.500000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.015 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :244.000000 8.000000 70.500000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.015 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :322.500000 8.000000 71.000000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.015 LOLHelper[8590:223132] BUT frame is :401.500000 8.000000 70.500000 18.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.015 LOLHelper[8590:223132] SubView frame is: :-3.000000 0.000000 480.000000 20.000000
2017-06-04 16:26:40.015 LOLHelper[8590:223132] headerView frame is: :0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 20.000000
```

2.i turn on the `userInteractionEnabled` of `UIButtons` `UIView1` `UIView2` , u can see in the code :

```
    #import "TableViewDataSource.h"


@implementation TableViewDataSource

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableCell;
@synthesize LHfetchedResultsController;
@synthesize numberOfRows;
@synthesize dataTemp;
@synthesize paused;
@synthesize type;
@synthesize imgAche;
@synthesize cellHeight;
@synthesize subHeaderViewFrame;

-(id)initWithTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView = tableView;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self setHeaderView];
    }
    return self;
}
-(UIView *)setHeaderView
{
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    UIView * container = [[UIView alloc] init];
    container.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, 20);
    container.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width*1.5, 20);
    headerView.tag = 01;
    headerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [container addSubview:headerView];
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        button.tag = i+10;
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"but0%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"but0%d s",i] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor brownColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        button.enabled = YES;
        button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [headerView addSubview:button];
    }
    UIButton *button01 = [headerView viewWithTag:11];
    UIButton *button02 = [headerView viewWithTag:12];
    UIButton *button03 = [headerView viewWithTag:13];
    UIButton *button04 = [headerView viewWithTag:14];
    UIButton *button05 = [headerView viewWithTag:15];
    UIButton *button06 = [headerView viewWithTag:16];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button01,button02,button03,button04,button05,button06);
    NSString * vflV1 = @"V:|-1-[button01]-1-|";
    NSString * vflV2 = @"V:|-1-[button02]-1-|";
    NSString * vflV3 = @"V:|-1-[button03]-1-|";
    NSString * vflV4 = @"V:|-1-[button04]-1-|";
    NSString * vflV5 = @"V:|-1-[button05]-1-|";
    NSString * vflV6 = @"V:|-1-[button06]-1-|";
    NSString * vflH1 = @"H:|-[button01]-[button02(==button01)]-[button03(==button01)]-[button04(==button01)]-[button05(==button01)]-[button06(==button01)]-|";

    NSArray * constraintsV1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV1 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsV2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV2 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsV3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV3 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsV4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV4 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsV5 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV5 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsV6 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflV6 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];
    NSArray * constraintsH1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflH1 options:0 metrics:NULL views:views];

    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV1];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV2];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV3];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV4];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV5];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsV6];
    [headerView addConstraints:constraintsH1];

    return container;
}
```

i have not find the reason

anyone could help me?

i also add some `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` into `UIView2`

thank u

Comment: May be there is a view covered your tableview's header part, check it.

Comment: my struct is like this:`self.tableView.tableHeaderView` contains a `UIView`, then `UIView` contains 6 `UIButtons`, and all code about these is over there, i can get buttons successfully in code, so i am not sure if there is another view which i have not noticed, could you tell me what view it may be.

Comment: Is there a view contains the tableView? And are there any other views else in that container view?

Comment: If you do **NOT** add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` into `UIView2` can you tap the buttons? If so, then you have found the problem.

Comment: @YunCHEN i have not add another `UIView` in to container view,and tableView is insert main `ViewController`, i can touch `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @DonMag right now i am not convenient to open my computer, so i can not check what u suggest, but is there any relation between `UISwipeGestureCognizer` and problem?

Comment: `2017-06-05 10:55:27.169 LOLHelper[13745:98406] tableHeaderView has 1 views
2017-06-05 10:55:27.169 LOLHelper[13745:98406] tableSubHeaderView has 6 views`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u Guys
i got the solution
reason is that 
        `[button addTarget:NULL action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
i set target NULL, and write `click:` in the same file, but actually i get the table from the main controller, so when i click button, xcode will find `click:` in the main controller, then can not find, so no responsibility.
after i set target self or write `click:` in main controller
it works